# How do I set the HTTP request header on a webservice reference?

Tags: web-services, http-headers

Here is the problem...

I have a webservice which works great with the JAVA code...

```
package com.mypackage.myproject;

 public class ExecuteGetOrder {


public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
     try {



        runGetOrder();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}




public static void runGetOrder() throws Exception
 {

        GetOrderDataInterface data = new GetOrderDataInterfaceProxy().getGetOrderDataInterface();
        ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub)data)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "ent=,user=UserName");
        ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub)data)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
        String RtrnDataXML = data.OrderInfo("OrderNumber");
        System.out.println(RtrnDataXML);




}



}
```

The Raw request looks like this...

```
POST http://win-bpqhaq6l0jt:8008/oms/services/GetOrderData HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: win-bpqhaq6l0jt:8008
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 366
Authorization: Basic ZW50PSx1c2VyPUEyTENNQWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ammoOrderInfo xmlns="http://a2lcm.rhinotechnology.com/"><order xmlns="">OrderNumber</order></OrderInfo></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I want to do this same thing in a VB.NET windows application. First I added the service reference, but when I try to use the class generated with this code...

```
    Dim OrderService As getOrderData.GetOrderDataInterfaceClient = New getOrderData.OrderDataInterfaceClient()
    Dim returnedXMl = OrderService.OrderInfo("Order")
```

I get back this...

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic host=10.20.100.7
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 948
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 21:25:05 GMT

<html><head><title>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font- family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-  family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p>  <b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA</h3></body></html>
```

So the question is how do I set the HTTP Authorization: on the request when made with...

```
Dim OrderService As getOrderData.GetOrderDataInterfaceClient = New GetOrderData.OrderDataInterfaceClient()
Dim returnedXMl = OrderService.OrderInfo("Order")
```

Comment: The solution you just added to your question should be an answer. You can answer your own question, and even accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for all trying to Basic authenticate with JBoss web services...

1) Add the following class (Code in vb)

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher

Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels

Imports System.ServiceModel.Description

Imports System.ServiceModel.Configuration

Imports System.Configuration

Public Class HttpUserAgentMessageInspector
Implements IClientMessageInspector

Private Const USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER As String = "Authorization"

Private m_userAgent As String

Public Sub New(ByVal userAgent As String)
    MyBase.New()
    Me.m_userAgent = userAgent
End Sub

Public Sub AfterReceiveReply(ByRef reply As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, ByVal correlationState As Object) Implements IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply

End Sub

Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, ByVal channel As System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest
    Dim httpRequestMessage As HttpRequestMessageProperty
    Dim httpRequestMessageObject As Object
    If request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessageObject) Then
        httpRequestMessage = CType(httpRequestMessageObject, HttpRequestMessageProperty)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER)) Then
            httpRequestMessage.Headers(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER) = Me.m_userAgent
        End If
    Else
        httpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessageProperty
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, Me.m_userAgent)
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage)
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
Public Class HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior
Implements IEndpointBehavior

Private m_userAgent As String

Public Sub New(ByVal userAgent As String)
    MyBase.New()
    Dim headerBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userAgent)
    Dim headerValue As String = ("Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(headerBytes))
    Me.m_userAgent = headerValue
End Sub
#Region "IEndpointBehavior Members"

Public Sub AddBindingParameters(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal bindingParameters As System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters

End Sub

Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal clientRuntime As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
    Dim inspector As HttpUserAgentMessageInspector = New HttpUserAgentMessageInspector(Me.m_userAgent)
    clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector)
End Sub

Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal endpointDispatcher As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior

End Sub

Public Sub Validate(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate

End Sub
#End Region
End Class
Public Class HttpUserAgentBehaviorExtensionElement
Inherits BehaviorExtensionElement

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property BehaviorType As Type
    Get
        Return GetType(HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior)
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Function CreateBehavior() As Object
    Return New HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior(UserAgent)
End Function

<ConfigurationProperty("userAgent", IsRequired:=True)> _
Public Property UserAgent As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("userAgent"), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me("userAgent") = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

2) Add the following XML code to your app.config between the system.serviceModel tags.

```
  <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LegacyServiceEndpointBehavior">
          <httpUserAgent userAgent="[[[myusername:password]]]" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
     <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
         <add name="httpUserAgent" type="  [[[myNamespace]]].HttpUserAgentBehaviorExtensionElement, [[[myProjectName]]], Version=1.0.0.0, Cultu re=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
       </behaviorExtensions>
       </extensions>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

3) Change the highlighted text to your namespace and project respectively.

4) Add the following text surrounded by [[[ ]]]to the end of the endpoint address. This part will need done to each service.

```
 <endpoint address="http://[[[ipAddress]]]/Location/GetOrderData"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RLCM.GetOrderDataInterfaceSoapBinding"
            contract="getOrderData.GetOrderDataInterface" name="GetOrderDataImplPort" [[[behaviorConfiguration="LegacyServiceEndpointBehavior"]]]/>
```

5) Now you should be able to use the code like this…

```
  Dim OrderService As getOrderData.GetOrderDataInterfaceClient = New getOrderData.GetOrderDataInterfaceClient()
  Dim returnedXML = OrderService.orderInfo("OrderNumber") and be authorized by the JBoss server and get back return data.
```